# BSOD ntoskrnl.exe MSI Creator 17 B11UH-405BE i9-11900H running Windows 11

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, windows-11, bsod

My MSI Creator 17 B11UH-405BE i9-11900H running Windows 11 was in screen saver and when I wanted to work again a BSOD appeared. After restarting, I wanted to view the source of the BSOD. It turned out that "ntoskrnl.exe" was the reason. After that I ran the DISM command: "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth". After that I used the chkdsk command: "chkdsk /f /r". When I restarted the laptop, it said it was fixing the C drive. At one point it said ETA: 1:23:42. But 16 hours later it still showed the same ETA. It was like the laptop freezed on that screen. So I powered off the laptop completely. After booting it went straight to the BIOS. I did a surface check on the SSD and it said that there were 1714 bad sectors.

I booted into Ubuntu 23.10 and tried to copy my C partition to another drive. I used gddrescue. It was an intense task and my laptop was getting very hot because the fan didn't work. On Windows, I can control my MSI fan. There is no native MSI program to control the fan on Linux, so I had to find another way: I found [OpenFreezeCenter (OFC)](https://github.com/YoCodingMonster/OpenFreezeCenter) on github. OFC helped me getting my fan to work at full speed so I could continue getting my data back via gddrescue. I managed to get 99,9% of my data back.

Now, how do I get my Windows boot partition copied? Should I just use gddrescue for that too? My plan is, once I copied those, that I will boot Windows 11 from a boot usb so I can try to fix boot problems. The goal is to get back my working machine without installing Windows 11 again.

What would be the best approach, now that I already copied my C drive partition to another drive?

See the pictures:

[CHKDSK](https://i.imgur.com/1cO7ZP3.jpeg)

[Bad sectors](https://i.imgur.com/ikflHSX.jpeg)

[Copy 1](https://i.imgur.com/AWNsSJ6.jpeg)

[Copy 2](https://i.imgur.com/pmNAvib.jpeg)

[Copy 3](https://i.imgur.com/TJPHcGb.jpeg)

Comment: Your storage device clearly has failed. Time to replace and reinstall Windows. Based on the number of bad sectors I see absolutely no way forward to your primary goal of booting into Windows without a reinstall

Comment: `I see absolutely no way forward to your primary goal of booting into Windows without a reinstall` .. **onto a new drive**.  You might be able to set it aside and get some recovery going with testdisk once you get back to windows.